# Using one table to update another in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, microsoft-excel-365

Let's say I have a table with two columns. The first column is a list of email addresses. The second column is a list of dates--let's say appointments. Each month I receive a table with updates, which could include:

- people rescheduling their appointments (new table shows same email, but different date)
- people joining the list (email does not appear in old table, but appears in new table)

Here's a toy example:

| Email-old | Date-old |
| --- | --- |
| amy@gmail.com | 1/2/2021 |
| bob@aol.com | 3/4/2021 |
| chris@yahoo.com | 5/6/2021 |
| dana@outlook.com | 7/8/2021 |
| erin@aim.com | 9/10/2021 |

| Email-new | Date-new |
| --- | --- |
| amy@gmail.com | 1/2/2021 |
| bob@aol.com | 3/11/2021 |
| fred@gmail.com | 11/12/2021 |

| Email-updated | Date-updated |
| --- | --- |
| amy@gmail.com | 1/2/2021 |
| bob@aol.com | 3/11/2021 |
| chris@yahoo.com | 5/6/2021 |
| dana@outlook.com | 7/8/2021 |
| erin@aim.com | 9/10/2021 |
| fred@gmail.com | 11/12/2021 |

Somehow I need to reconcile the old table of emails/appointments with the new table of emails/appointments. What is the best way to do this? VLOOKUP? XLOOKUP? INDEX MATCH? Something else?

Something I've tried: concatenating the email addresses with their respective dates in each table, then doing an XLOOKUP to see if the new email/date combination is in the list of old email/date combinations. It seems like the results were accurate, but there were so many discrepancies that it became cumbersome to edit the list manually. Thoughts? Advice?

Note: I'm open to non-Excel solutions but ideally this would all happen in Excel. These tables are going to be updated by people who mainly work in Excel. Also in case it matters the old table has maybe one to two thousand rows while the new table has around five hundred.

Thank you!

Comment: It is best to upload some screenshots or examples to let us know the expected results you want.

Comment: You are trying to use a hammer for a screw. Excel is not meant for this tasks. But yes, you can do it. But prepare to write your own macro for it. Especially when there is unknown variable 
 _possibly other things I haven't thought of_ ...

Comment: Good point. I'll post some examples when I have more time.

@Lluser "Possibly other things I haven't thought of" was more tongue in cheek than anything. If not Excel, then what?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `SourceTable` where will be new data appended and then is possible to consider latest data as valid ones.

[image: POC table]
//Sorry for Date format mess in SourceTable ValidDate column. It's only cosmetic bug calculation works properly.

Here is [POC table in Excel Online](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArVkYVSHnABFii_aI9FKb57OkaqA?e=bWyMNA)

**It uses automatic spill of formula result available in newer versions of Excel** *

### Used formulas

**MainTable**

- Email row (only in the first row)
  `=UNIQUE(SourceTable[Email])`
- ValidDate column (only in the first row)
  `=INDEX(SourceTable[ValidDate],MATCH(UNIQUE(SourceTable[Email]),SourceTable[Email],0))`

**SourceTable**

- Row column
  `=ROW()-ROW(SourceTable[#Headers])`
- ValidRow
  `=MAX(([@Email]=[Email])*[Row])`
- ValidDate
  `=INDEX([Date],[@ValidRow])`

ValidRow could be part of ValidDate formula, I left it separate for better understanding

*Excel for Microsoft 365 Excel for Microsoft 365 for Mac Excel for the web Excel 2021 Excel 2021 for Mac Excel for iPad Excel Web App Excel for iPhone Excel for Android tablets Excel for Android phones